# UICollectionView horizontal flow layout: how to make cells go left-right top-down?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm using UICollectionView with different sections, the problem is within a section if there are not enough item, the only items are centred, is there a way to make it layout cells to be from left to right and top to bottom? Without adding transparent placeholder cells?
Thanks

edit:

Screen shot added, so section 1 has the big orange bar and two small green bars, the one on the right of big orange bar should be in section 1, so I want it to be below the big orange bar, next to another green bar which is already there.

Also, say if section 1 has only 1 big orange bar, I want it to be top aligned, but it is centered.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you give a picture of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: still can't get what you are trying to achieve? Do u want to make a collection view with varying cell size?

Comment: @Meera See the green rectangle with "this green bar should be in section 1"? My question was why is it not below the big orange bar, they are all in section 1.

Comment: @hzxu: You mean the green cell should be below the orange cell right? Check you collection view frame. Collection view rearranges cells inside it according to the view frame and layout used.